# Error:org/slf4j/impl/Log4jLoggerFactory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, slf4j

I have written a simple testing project in Java and I keep getting the above message when I try to compile it. Gradle build was done without a problem and what is more my project runs on different computers without errors. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you've forgot to include the actual error message.

Comment: It's in the header. It is all there is.

Comment: That can't be all there is.

Comment: Believe me, it is. That's why I have no idea where to look for the source of the problem.

Comment: Is SLF4J included in the build path for the project?

Comment: Yes, it is included.

Comment: Is it a Java 9 project? Does the issue occure with new sample project?

Comment: Yes, it is Java 9 project but I encounter it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days worth of frustration I got rid of Linux Mint and installed Windows 10. The problem disappeared and the project compiles nicely. Though I still don't know what caused it in the first place.